# Integrating ActionCable with Webpacker in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-5.1, webpacker

I am upgrading my app from Rails 5.0 to 5.1, and there is one thing I can't find being mentioned anywhere - usage of Webpacker to process ActionCable JavaScript files.

I realise that Webpacker and the asset pipeline are supposed to work side by side, but now that we have Webpack build into Rails it would be a waste not to use it for files located in `assets` directory (which is where ActionCable lives), yet I can't find any information on how to do that.

I'm specifically interested in Babel, so I could use ES6. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `# Gemfile
gem 'sprockets', '>= 3.0.0'
gem 'sprockets-es6' and use ES6 with babel transpiled with sprockets :)

Comment: I've thought about this option before, but with Rails 5.1 it seems like an unnecessary dependency. I'd really like to avoid that.

Comment: So what's your exact question?

Comment: Is it possible to transpile JS files located in `assets/javascripts` directory the same way as the files in `javascript/packs` directory?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you need to replace the ActionCable implementation of rails, which is written for sprockets with something that is written in module syntax, to make proper use of webpacker. 
Specifically this line in your `cable.js`

`require action_cable`

Everything else should be easily portable. 
There seem to be a couple of implementations for ActionCable and modules around: 
https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:ActionCable

Specifically this looks exactly what you are searching for: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/actioncable-modules

There seems to be [some movement](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33079) on the side of Rails to use Webpacker as a complete sprocket replacement in Rails 6, so it might be worth waiting, instead of creating something that builds on third party modules.